# Finding the maxima of this integral

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I had this complex integral

> If $0 \leq y \leq 1$, find the maximum value of the integral
>   $$
> \int_0^y \left(x^4 + (y-y^2) \right)^{1/2}\, dx
> $$

I differentiated the integral using the leibniz rule and equated it to 0.
The problem is that I obtain a expression containing a biquadratic in a square root and an integral. The biquadratic inside the root is always positive when I checked it and the integral was easily evaluated. The complexity of the problem kept on increasing as I started getting fractional exponents. 
Please help me on this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: May be he mean minimum of  $\displaystyle \int^{y}_{0}\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}dx$ for $y\in [0,1]$

Comment: Are you sure about $x^4$ ? This seems to lead to elliptic integrals.

Comment: That is not a complex integral.  It is a real integral.

Comment: @jacky yeah exactly thats what i meant

Comment: @WilliamElliot by complex i meant challenging..sorry for that

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah x^4 term is there in the question.

Comment: Then this is a very difficult problem (at least to me).

Comment: @Shashank if you agree with jacky (as evidently you seem to from both comments and your accepted answer), you should correct your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you mean $\max$ of

$$\displaystyle \int^{y}_{0}\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}dx$$ subjected to $0 \leq y\leq 1$

$\bullet\; $ From $$\sqrt{a+b}\leq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$$ for all $a,b\geq 0$

$$\displaystyle \int^{y}_{0}\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}dx\leq \int^{y}_{0}x^2dx+\int^{y}_{0}y(1-y)dx$$

$$= \frac{y^3}{3}+y^2(1-y)=\frac{1}{3}y\cdot y \cdot (3-2y)$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\bigg[y\cdot y \cdot (3-2y)\bigg]\leq \frac{1}{3}\bigg[\frac{y+y+(3-2y)}{3}\bigg]^3=\frac{1}{3}$$

$$\Longrightarrow \bigg(\int^{y}_{0}\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}dx\bigg)_{\max}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

If there is no typo, I have the feeling that you face a difficult problem.

If
$$f(y)=\int_0^y g(x,y)\,dx$$ then
$$f'(y)=g(y,y)+\int_0^y \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}\,dx$$ So, for your case
$$f'(y)=\sqrt{y \left(y^3-y+1\right)}+\frac{1-2y }2\int_0^y \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+y-y^2}}$$ and the last integral involves elliptic integral of the first kind or gaussian hypergeometric function.

The most attractive form I found is 
$$\int_0^y \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+y-y^2}}=\frac{\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{4};\frac{y^3}{y-1}\right)}{\sqrt{
\frac{1}{y}-1}}$$ Now, the only thing I was able to do is some numerical analysis work which shows that the zero of $f'(y)$ is very close to $0.888$.

I faced the same kind of trouble with $f(y)$ and the best I found is
$$f(y)=y \sqrt{(1-y) y} \,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4};\frac{5}{4};\frac{y^3}{y-1}\right)$$ which, evaluated for $y=0.888$ gives a maximum value close to $0.397$.

A complete numerical work on $f(y)$ shows that the maximum value is $0.396745$ at $y=0.887651$.